# Music button problems

Tags: android, button, android-music-player

I have trouble with buttons. I have 31 different mp3 file. I add 31 button. When I pressed 29th button 30 and 31 isn't working in my phone. Emulator working is fine. I have one more problem, when I came mainactivity and then again join my mp3 page sometimes aren't work all buttons.

```
public class voice extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bt;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice);

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });


        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice2);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp2.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice3);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp3.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final MediaPlayer mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice4);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp4.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        final MediaPlayer mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice5);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp5.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        final MediaPlayer mp6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice6);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp6.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        final MediaPlayer mp7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice7);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp7.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        final MediaPlayer mp8 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice8);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp8.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        final MediaPlayer mp9 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice9);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp9.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        final MediaPlayer mp10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice10);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp10.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        final MediaPlayer mp11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice11);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp11.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        final MediaPlayer mp12 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice12);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp12.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        final MediaPlayer mp13 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice13);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp13.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
        final MediaPlayer mp14 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice14);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp14.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
        final MediaPlayer mp15 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice15);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp15.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
        final MediaPlayer mp16 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice16);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp16.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
        final MediaPlayer mp17 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice17);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp17.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button18);
        final MediaPlayer mp18 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice18);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp18.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
        final MediaPlayer mp19 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice19);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp19.start();
            }
        });
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button20);
        final MediaPlayer mp20 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice20);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp20.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
        final MediaPlayer mp21 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice21);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp21.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button22);
        final MediaPlayer mp22 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice22);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp22.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);
        final MediaPlayer mp23 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice23);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp23.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button24);
        final MediaPlayer mp24 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice24);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp24.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button25);
        final MediaPlayer mp25 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice25);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp25.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button26);
        final MediaPlayer mp26 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice26);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp26.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button27);
        final MediaPlayer mp27 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice27);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp27.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button28);
        final MediaPlayer mp28 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice28);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp28.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button29);
        final MediaPlayer mp29 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice29);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp29.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button30);
        final MediaPlayer mp30 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice30);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp30.start();
            }
        });

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button31);
        final MediaPlayer mp31 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice31);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp31.start();
            }
        });


    }



}
}
```

Comment: It would probably be better to reuse 1 MediaPlayer instance instead of creating one for each mp3...

Comment: Creating a bunch of MediaPlayer instances is an overkill.

Comment: Can someone give me a example in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Media Player docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

The idea is, you don't need to create your players. Use just one media player but, release previous data before using next one:

```
 if (mplayer !=null) {
     mplayer.stop();
     mplayer.release();
     mplayer = null;
 }
 mplayer = new  MediaPlayer();
 mplayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),
                  Uri.parse(CONSTANTS.RES_PREFIX + R.raw.id));
 mplayer.prepare();
 mplayer.start();
```

Your code:

```
public class voice extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bt;
MediaPlayer mplayer;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice);

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.voice1;
             startNewVoice(path);
            }
        });
   }
void startNewVoice(String pathToFile) {
   if (mplayer !=null) {
       mplayer.stop();
       mplayer.release();
       mplayer = null;
   }
   mplayer = new  MediaPlayer();
   try{
       mplayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(pathToFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   mplayer.prepare();
   mplayer.start();
}
```

}

Look at onClick. You need create path for each buttons and send it to startNewVoice method. Don't forget approve if its work for you

Comment: I looked Media Player docs, but I don't understand. I'm not good coder. Can u give me a example in my code.

Comment: once2go dude thank u very very very much. U are my hero now :) thank u man